# How to add routes in angularjs dynamically from database values?

Tags: angularjs

I have a method in my web api controller which will return me an array of objects.

The objects contain the route name, template url, controller name.
In my main module of the application, I want to make the `$http` call to the web api and read and loop through the collection and add them to `$routeprovider.when()`.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? This information is not enough to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I have a method in my web api controller which will return me a array of objects. The objects contains the route name, template url, controller name.
In my main module of the application, I want to make the $http call to the web api and read those details and add them to $routeprovider.when().
Please let me know, if you need any other details

Comment: dynamically making use of controllers and route? No idea there mate.

Comment: No Issues, thanks for your time and effort Gandalf :)

Comment: Cheers Mate! Best of luck.